# connect to server with netcat and receive *multiple* files with one request/connection

Tags: tcp, http, netcat, node.js, npm

Say I have an http or tcp server running, which serves tarballs (.tgz files).

Is there some way I can receive files individually so I can do something like this:

```
nc localhost 5000 | how can I read multiple files here and save each to disk?
```

to explain further, when I connect to the server, I'd like it to respond with a series of .tgz files. My question is, if it's a tcp server, how can I write each file so that it comes in separately.

The only thing I would know how to do would be to stream the data to a single file, but I don't know how to write out multiple files.

This is potentially an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44894223/1223975

But I don't understand how to write each file out individually.

Comment: http multipart might be the way, if pure tcp makes this hard. *one problem is that the client does not know in advance how many files it will receive, the server dictates that.*

Comment: Do you control the server?

Comment: yeah I do, I control both server and client, it's all locally running - I think this answer might work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44894223/1223975

Comment: but I guess after `tar -x` runs, I don't know how to save each file to disk, or how that works

Comment: Yes, that should work. That's what I usually use (either that or a variation of `ssh tar c ... | tar x ...` if security is needed). `tar` will unarchive each file in the incoming archive to separate files.

Comment: right if you can add an answer demonstrating how to save each file to disk like that, I will upvote etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the server, do:

```
tar c file1 file2 dir1 file3 ... | nc -l 5000
```

Then, on the client, do:

```
nc server 5000 | tar x
```

Or, slower, but more secure:

```
ssh server tar c file1 file2 dir1 file3 ... | tar x
```

For example:

```
$ ssh localhost 'cd /etc; tar c passwd nsswitch.conf' | (d=$(mktemp -d); tar xv -C "$d"; ls -l "$d"; rm -r "$d")
passwd
nsswitch.conf
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 muru muru  529 Feb 16  2017 nsswitch.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 muru muru 2631 Apr 24 18:18 passwd
```

Comment: does tar -x just save all the files to current working directory? i am confused.

Comment: @AlexanderMills yes, unless you set a different directory using the `-C` option

Comment: this works, but I have one small problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336674/tar-x-command-is-recreating-original-filepath-of-file-with-mkdir-p